# How the current from circuit cross a capacitor dielectrics?

Tags: capacitor, ac

I've intensively studying electronic circuits there are few months and this is the first time I feel my brain stuck.

How can the current coming from the circuit cross a capacitor to the other side if there is a dielectrics layer between it? Even if it is AC it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It can't, current doesn't flow through capacitor. Capacitor just stores charges on his plates.

Comment: I suggest you to read this book http://www.amazon.com/Circuit-Analysis-Dummies-John-Santiago-ebook/dp/B00C6ECOOS

Comment: This video might help you better understand it: [Does Current Flow Through A Capacitor?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppWBwZS4e7A)

Answer (score 4):

The current does not flow through the capacitor in the sense that an electron goes in on one side and comes out on the other side. The dielectric prevents this.
What does happen is that an electron on one plate of the capacitor forms a negative charge. This negative charge attracts a positive charge on the other plate of the capacitor. In other words, it repels an electron on the other plate.

Current is simply movement of charge / electrons.

A DC current is movement of charge in one direction (not possible through a capacitor).

An AC current is movement of charge alternating in opposite directions (possible through a capacitor).

Comment: Great explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Electrons do not jump from one side of the dielectric to the other. Capacitors are open circuits. They store electrons and discharge them from the same side.

In a DC powered series RC circuit, the half of the capacitor attached to the more negative section of the circuit will begin storing electrons from the DC supply, becoming more negatively charged and forcing the positive half of the capacitor to release electrons and become more positively charged. This continues until the capacitor is "fully charged." The process reverses when you discharge a capacitor -- all the extra electrons on the negative side want to move toward the positive side, and bring the potential voltage to zero.

The same concept occurs in AC circuits, but the alternating nature of things causes capacitors lose impedance as the frequency grows. At high frequencies, capacitors can act like a short.

Comment: you said [..]"forcing the positive half of the capacitor to release electrons and become more positively charged.". How can que positive side release electrons if they don't touch themselves? Don't you mean the negative side becomes negative towards positive side of the capacitor?

Comment: The electrons on the negative side of the theoretical series RC circuit repel the electrons on the positive side. The current is created when a potential voltage is introduced to the circuit, so electron movement (current) is based on that.

Answer (score 2):

This animation from [wiki commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Capacitor_diagrams#/media/File:CapacitorHydraulicAnalogyAnimation.gif) shows the water-flow analogon for a capacitor:

[image]

The water can not pass the red membrane, but as the membrane is flexible, water (charge) will flow into the pipe on one side and out of it on the other side, if there is some pressure (voltage).

If the membrane is bent and there is no external pressure, the membrane itself generates pressure, like a charged, but disconnected capacitor.

And the more flexible the membrane is, the more water can rush in for a given pressure. This is similar to the capacitance: The higher this value, the more charge flows into the capacitor for a certain voltage.